# replace String with variable in sed gives error

Tags: shell, sed

I have the following shell script to replace the string in file

`Port=7070`

`IP=1.1.1.1`

`NewBoshURL="var BOSH_URL = \"http://$IP:$Port/http-bind/\";"`

`sed -i 's/var BOSH_URL.*/'$NewBoshURL'/' index.html`

It gives me error below

> sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here:

- variable contains spaces, use double quotes to protect them
- variable contains slash, try another delimit(such as `@`)

  ```
  sed -i "s@var BOSH_URL.*@$NewBoshURL@" index.html
  ```